# newsd eating my limited bandwidth

Tags: network

Big Sur 11.1 and iMac Pro.   I am on a slow (8Mbps) internet connection and the newsd program is consistently eating up more than 10% of that.  I assume it's related to Apple News but can't find any documentation.  Does anyone else see 1Mbs constant downloading from newsd?  I base that info on an iStat Menus readout--and the fact that killing newsd in Activity Monitor instantly brings faster internet to all other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too see an incredible amount of data usage from newsd. In my case, around 28GB was downloaded in 24 hours.

I’ve opened a ticket with Apple Support.